# Convert PDF to gDoc

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use this script:

```
function pdfToDoc() {  
  var fileBlob = DriveApp.getFileById('XXXX').getBlob();  
  var resource = {
    title: fileBlob.getName(),
    mimeType: fileBlob.getContentType()
  };
  var options = {
    ocr: true
  };
  var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, fileBlob, options);  
  Logger.log(docFile.alternateLink);  
}
```

but I am getting this error `

> "Unexpected error while getting the method or property getBlob on
>   object DriveApp.File."

`

If I make it a file.getName(), it succeeds so it isn't an access issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: This code works when I test it on my drive. My only guess is it's something going on with the specific PDF, have you tried with another small/basic PDF?

Comment: Where does the error occurs in your script?